# What does this sentence mean: "We've gotten too good at pushing our own buttons."

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

A neuroscientist who specializes in eating behavior and obesity say: "We've gotten too good at pushing our own buttons".

This structure is very strange to me: have gotten + adjective + at + gerund.

Does the sentence refer to the fact that today we are surrounded by such hyperpalatable foods that we can not stop eating?

Comment: It means that we become very good at answering our brains when they call us for fast food.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the chapter, what I believe this sentence refers to is our propensity as humans to fulfill the desires of our brain. It talks about how these 'hyperpalatable foods' are 'more attractive to the human brain'.

So when it says "We've gotten too good at pushing our own buttons" - it means that we've become too good at fuflilling that 'bliss point' of salt, sugar and fat and effectively making our brain happy.

The 'buttons' refer to the processes that fulfill this function - we can identify what foods satisfy the urges of addiction